# Analyze the following fallacy:

Tags: logic

In a city council says a councilman: "In a time of crisis, wages are not very high and we see with evil eyes the money that we are going in taxes, the more services, the more taxes we have to pay. So I am against the construction of recreational areas, all, in fact, we are. "

Comment: Not very clear the statement of the "fallacy" : "So..., all, in fact, we are."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of [hidden premises](http://www.theskepticsguide.org/resources/logical-fallacies).

1st premise) People do not like taxes increase.

2nd premise) In order to have more services, we have to pay more taxes.

Therefore :

Conclusion) I am against the construction of recreational areas.

Hidden premises :

A) To have new recreational areas is part of to have more services.

B) I (we) have to do only what people like.